# output console in Eclipse and arrays syntax

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and a bit confused with arrays, what seems to be wrong in this code, as eclipse output console is saying **** Build of configuration Debug for project Project ****

Internal Builder is used for build               **
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -omain.o ..\main.c
gcc -oProject.exe main.o
C:...\Documents\eclipse\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5........\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot open output file Project.exe: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 472  ms.

I will really appreciate your help...

```
int main()
{
    int box[2][2], rows, cols, x = 1;

    for (rows=0; rows < 2; rows++)
    {

        for (cols=0; cols < 2; cols++)
        {
            box[rows][cols] = x++;
            printf("%d", box[rows][cols]);
        }

    }
    fflush(stdout);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: works perfectly fine in gcc if you remove getch();. which environment are you working and which compiler are you using ?

Comment: Refer This thread <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648808/cannot-open-a-exe-error-in-c>.

Comment: I'm Using Eclipse... but i'm switching to Pelles C... might look gcc too thanks.

Comment: it's working fine in Pelles C. YAY! :)
I have a question confused with arrays, the statement box[rows][cols] = x++; says increment x right? but x=1 already, so the value of box[rows][cols] or box[0][0] = 2 ? why in the print out it says 1?

Answer (score 1):

x++ is post increment so the value of x is used and then incremented and hence box[0][0] is 1

Comment: i'm sorry... in what statement does X++ do the increment, from what i understand box[rows][cols] = x++ is not equal to box[rows][cols] = 2, because you said box[rows][cols] = 1; does it mean will it run the whole statement in the inner for loop once and then after printf("%d", box[rows][cols]) that's the only time x increments to 2?

Comment: read this link to know about the increment and decrement operators http://cprogrammingcodes.blogspot.in/2011/09/increment-and-decrement-operators.html