# build error in Eclipse for C program

Tags: eclipse, build, permission-denied

My project is named silence. I get the following error even when I build even a simple printf statement.

Build of configuration Debug for project silence **

Internal Builder is used for build               **
gcc -osilence.exe source\read_pcm.o
c:/eclipse/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.1-dw2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file silence.exe: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 141  ms.

Please advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648808/cannot-open-a-exe-error-in-c

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451816/compiling-with-gcc-on-windows-7-mingw32-bin-ld-exe-cannot-open-output-file-a-e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program may still be running. Try stopping it by using the small red square on the console window (the one for your program). Another way is switching to the "Debug" perspective, selecting your running program, and stopping it there (also the small red square). ([link](http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/ar01s05.jsp))